# Bash Script Echoing double quotes when I don't want it too

Tags: bash, echo, quotes

I don't know what is going on here. I've made more than my share of bash scripts. Searching the past questions just had people asking how to make the quotes persistent.

When echoing to /dev/tty the quotes are echoing as well.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
currentfile=This.File;
echo 'About to output' > /dev/tty;
echo “The Currect File is $currentfile” > /dev/tty;
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

which would echo:

```
\#'About to output'
\#"The Currect File is ??
```

If I put a space after $currectfile I'll get a more correct but not what I am looking for of:

```
\#'About to output'
\#"The Currect File is This.File "
```

The output I am expecting is simply:

```
\#About to output
\#The Currect File is This.File
```

When inputting this line in interactive it echos as expected.

Comment: While I was just making an example, I executed my example program and got the output of Macbook-Pro-15:Desktop user$ bash anotherDirectory/test.sh 
About to output
“The Currect File is ??
Macbook-Pro-15:Desktop user$ sh anotherDirectory/test.sh 
About to output
“The Currect File is ??       So while the single quotes are gone here but show up in my main program the double quotes are the same.

Comment: It looks like you have U+201C (LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) and U+201D (RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK) in your code, as opposed to U+0022 (QUOTATION MARK).

Comment: CORRECT!  I just need to change them all. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by change? Are you looking for code to replace those unicode quotes with regular `"`

Answer (score 2):

Let's run your code through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) to automatically check for common problems:

```
echo “The Currect File is $currentfile” > /dev/tty;
     ^-- SC1015: This is a unicode double quote. Delete and retype it.
```

And let's do that:

```
echo "The Currect File is $currentfile" > /dev/tty;
```